# Book suggestion in higher dimensional geometry especially regarding lines and hyper-planes in high-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request

Let us assume we are in 4-dimensional space comprising 4-tuples: $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. Let us consider a plane $\Gamma_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the equation of $x_1=x_2=0$. And let us consider another plane $\Gamma_2$:$x_1=1, x_4=0$. The two planes do not intersect each other also they are not parallel to each other. This non-parallel and no intersection property for two planes is possible in $\mathbb{R}^4$ but not possible in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Any book suggestion containing these examples in higher dimensional geometry especially regarding lines and hyper-planes in high-dimensional space?

Comment: "*This non-parallel and no intersection property for two planes is possible in $\mathbb{R}^4$ but not possible in $\mathbb{R}^3$*" $\;-\;$ Just like [skew lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines) are possible in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but not in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Don't know that you'll find a book dedicated to such examples, though they should be covered in any introductory material. Also, if you don't mean to restrict the question to geometric approaches exclusively, then you may want to add [`linear-algebra`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) as a tag.

Comment: A review about nD affine spaces : https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/geombchap2.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Polytopes_(book) .. I have not read this but it might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest "An introduction to geometry of n dimensions" by Sommerville, Dover editions, which describes a lot of polytopes (analogous to polyhedrons in 3 dimensions) :

https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Extras/Sommerville_Geometry/

The best movie on this subject, (in English or any other language), made by three french researchers (Etienne Ghys, Arélien Alvarez and Josh Leys) : "Dimensions, a walk through mathematics" :

https://youtu.be/6cpTEPT5i0A

It starts at a very simple level, and progressively explains how to have a good vision of the fourth dimension and its polytopes.

It is also an excellent visual introduction to complex numbers, in chapter 5.

Comment: More a comment than an answer...